ggplot one color on top of another issue
I am using ggplot and use variable in color= option, this variable has 4 levels. As a result I am having the plot as below. Is there a way to have each color equally important, i.e. not like now that colors are being plotted on top of each other?
My current code:
myData %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = visit, y = response, group = patient, color=color)) +
  geom_line()

I know that it is possible to change the order in which the colors are plotted, for example
myData %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = visit, y = response, group = patient, color=color)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_line(data = myData[myData$color == "1",], aes(x = visit, y = response, group = patient, color=color))

but it is not of interest for me, I would like to have colors equally important if possible


You might look at ggblend.  https://mjskay.github.io/ggblend/

What does "equally important" mean?

There are so many lines here, you might prefer the results with some combination of  thinner lines (linewidth = 0.3 for instance) and transparency (alpha = 0.3 for instance).
